# Using JOIN to filter data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data in a table called `PROD`

```
| Project | Position | Status |
|---------|----------|--------|
| 1       | 1        | A      |
| 1       | 2        | A      |
| 2       | 1        | A      |
| 2       | 2        | B      |
| 3       | 1        | B      |
| 3       | 2        | B      |
| 4       | 1        | A      |
| 4       | 2        | A      |
```

I'm trying to get all the `Projects` that has at least one `Position` with `Status = B`.

```
| Project | Position | Status |
|---------|----------|--------|
| 2       | 1        | A      |
| 2       | 2        | B      |
| 3       | 1        | B      |
| 3       | 2        | B      |
```

I've tried using a `JOIN` like this:

`SELECT * FROM PROD A JOIN PROD B ON A.PROD-Project = B.PROD-Project WHERE B.PROD-Status = 'B'`

This give me an empty response.

Comment: Are there more columns in your real tables?? As the example data shows you are storing redundant data ideally this data could/should be normalized better.

Comment: @RaymondNijland the real data is a bit messy. It is actually coming from a COBOL DAT file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.* FROM PROD p 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM PROD
  WHERE Project = p.Project AND Status = 'B'
)
```

or with `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM PROD
WHERE Project IN (SELECT Project FROM PROD WHERE Status = 'B')
```

If you want a solution with `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
FROM PROD p JOIN PROD pp
ON pp.Project = p.Project 
WHERE pp.Status = 'B'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b18fd2b30ba0e79ed7325628b489efe4).
Results:

```
> Project | Position | Status
> ------: | -------: | :-----
>       2 |        1 | A     
>       2 |        2 | B     
>       3 |        1 | B     
>       3 |        2 | B
```

Comment: The LEFT JOIN gives results as a INNER JOIN because of the filter on the PROD pp table , so ideally you would want to use INNER JOIN to optimize see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f6f914affe7fde39b17a1b987666ac31)

Comment: @forpas. What does `SELECT 1` mean in the first solution with `EXISTS`?

Comment: @g3blv it is a dummy column that is not important. It could be `select 0` or `select *`. The important thing here i sthat the select *returns* or `does not return` simething so EXISTS is true or false.

Comment: @g3blv EXISTS expects a boolean.. `SELECT 1`  is the most confirm way of writting it, but it really does not matter what you write at least not in MySQL there see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=12bcb0ed979e0d1a35d8c0f6307ef0d1)

Comment: RaymondNijland and forpas great explanation

Comment: @g3blv but i would normally choose the `INNER JOIN` over the `EXISTS()` and `IN()` as the MySQL optimizer tends to optimize INNER JOIN's much better assuming correct indexing offcource.  Well in this case it might be close as the INNER JOIN needs to have a DISTINCT..

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a join wit the subquery

```
select * from  PROD 
INNER JOIN (
  select  distinct project 
  from  PROD 
  where status ='B';
  ) t on t.project = PROD.project
```

Answer (score 0):

> > I'm trying to get all the Projects that has at least one Position with Status = B.

No need for a JOIN, just do:

SELECT DISTINCT PROD.Project WHERE PROD.Status='B'